# How to properly search and parse an array using a sequence of elements as the target

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, parsing

I have a byte array that looks something like this:

```
byte[] exampleArray = new byte[] 
                      { 0x01, 0x13, 0x10, 0xe2, 0xb9, 0x13, 0x10, 0x75, 0x3a, 0x13 };
```

My end goal is to split this array into sub array's anytime I see the sequence `{ 0x13, 0x10 }`. So my desired result on the example array would be:

```
{ 0x01 }
{ 0xe2, 0xb9 }
{ 0x75, 0x3a, 0x13 }
```

Ideally, I would also need to know that the final array, `{ 0x75, 0x3a, 0x13 }`, did not end with the search sequence so that I could work with that as a special case.

Any thoughts on the best approach?

Comment: What if you convert your array ot ascii string and use string.split? Something like `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(exampleArray).Split(...)`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4617264/848330

Comment: `string delimiter = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 0x13, 0x10 });`

Comment: michael - just being curious - is the described problem the real one, or is it a fragment of your solution to something else? Aren't you by chance trying to "repair" some binary data that was "CR-LF-translated" and ended up with all \x10 replaced with \x13\x10? Or maybe you are trying to split some binary data that were sent "line by line" by some device/service that failed to notice that data is binary not textual?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl This is absolutely a small fragment of a larger application. I'm sending data over a socket connection. The data is being serialized to a byte array and I am adding the 0x13,0x10 as an indication for the end of each message. On the receive side, I need to maintain a queue of incoming data and parse out the messages using the end of message sequence.

Comment: @michael.mankus: This is exactly what I was concerned about. If your description is accurate, Terminating a **BINARY** message with magic number almost always will cause problems, because there usually is a slight chance that **your binary message will contain data equal to the magic number**.

Comment: @michael.mankus: If you **know** that `0x13 0x10` will **never** occur in the "data serialized as byte array", than you can ignore. But, seriously, this is .Net/C#. How can you be sure that the serializer doesn't emit 13-10 pair in some circumstances? Unless you exactly know what you are doing, if you can, please stop formatting your messsages like this. Instead of `[message] 0x13 0x10` change the format to `[message-length][message]`. Or, if you don't know the length, emit it in chunks of known length and padding, ie. `[padlength][1..1024message][padding]`. Or think of something better:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<byte[]> Split(byte[] bArray)
        {
            List<byte[]> result = new List<byte[]>();
            List<byte> tmp = new List<byte>();
            int i, n = bArray.Length;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if (bArray[i] == 0x13 && (i + 1 < n && bArray[i + 1] == 0x10))
                {
                    result.Add(tmp.ToArray());
                    tmp.Clear();
                    i++;
                }
                else
                    tmp.Add(bArray[i]);
            }
            if (tmp.Count > 0)
                result.Add(tmp.ToArray());
            return result;
        }
```

The last array can not end with sequence, any splited part does not contein separator.
Only byte 0x13 can happen, so if this is importane for you, you can jast check last byte of last sub array.

Comment: This will result in index out of bounds errors; you need to ensure that your `for` loop doesn't go all of the way to the end if you check the "next" item within the body.

Comment: I accepted this answer as it is the closest to what I ended up doing.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this that should work in the general case (obviously with better error checking!):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        byte[] exampleArray = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8 };

        var test = exampleArray.PartitionBySubset(new byte[] { 2, 3 }).ToList();
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> PartitionBySubset<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, IEnumerable<T> subset) where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        // Get our subset into a array so we can refer to items by index and so we're not iterating it multiple times.
        var SubsetArray = subset.ToArray();
        // The position of the subset array we will check
        var SubsetArrayPos = 0;
        // A list to hold current items in the subsequence, ready to be included in the resulting sequence
        var CurrentList = new List<T>();

        foreach (var item in sequence)
        {
            // add all items (ones part of the subset will be removed)
            CurrentList.Add(item);
            if (item.Equals(SubsetArray[SubsetArrayPos]))
            {
                // This item is part of the subset array, so move to the next subset position
                SubsetArrayPos++;
                // Check whether we've checked all subset positions
                if (SubsetArrayPos == SubsetArray.Length)
                {
                    // If so, then remove the subset items from the current list
                    CurrentList.RemoveRange(CurrentList.Count - SubsetArray.Length, SubsetArray.Length);
                    // Reset the position
                    SubsetArrayPos = 0;

                    // Only return the list if it's not empty (the main list could start with a subset)
                    if (CurrentList.Count != 0)
                    {
                        // Return the list we have now since it's been ended.
                        yield return CurrentList;
                        // Create a new list ready for more items
                        CurrentList = new List<T>();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // This item isn't part of the subset, so next time check the start.
                SubsetArrayPos = 0;
            }
        }

        // If we get to the end and have some items to return, then return them.
        if (CurrentList.Count != 0)
            yield return CurrentList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string example = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(exampleArray);
string delimiter = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 0x13, 0x10 });
string[] result = example.Split(new string[] { delimiter});
string ending = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new byte[] { 0x75, 0x3a, 0x13 });
bool ends = example.EndsWith(ending);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would proceed with checking the current and previous array element. Like this:

```
int[] data = ...;

// start from second byte, to be able to touch the previous one
int i = 1;
while (i < data.Length)
{
    if (data[i-1] == 0x13 && data[i] == 0x10)
    {
        // end of subarray reached
        Console.WriteLine();
        i+=2;
    }
    else
    {
        // output the previous character, won't be used in the next iteration
        Console.Write(data[i-1].ToString("X2"));
        i++;
    }
}

// process the last (or the only) byte of the array, if left
if (i == data.Length)
{
    // apparently there wasn't a delimiter in the array's last two bytes
    Console.Write(data[i-1].ToString("X2"));
    Console.WriteLine(" - no 0x13 010");
}
```

*Note: Console output for the sake of demonstration. Replace with actual data processing.*